# Can I use a SRAM Powerlink on a Shimano chain

Tags: chain

Have 9 speed Shimano chain that I need to shorten.

I don't have the Shimano pin so I need to go buy one.
Could just reuse the regular pin but I already broke one chain tool trying that.

I think the SRAM Powerlink would be more convenient.

Is it safe to use the SRAM Powerlink on a Shimano chain?
Or is there some other reusable connector (master link) for a Shimano chain?

Comment: Sorry I found a duplicate on this site.  They use the term Powerlock so I did not find it at first.  I don't know if I should just delete the question.

Comment: The Powerlink will work, as will the KMC quicklink or the Connex one. The manufacturers say the quick links should only be used with their brand of chain primarily to boost sales and cover their legal hinds (so technically its YMMV, but not a problem anyone has ever encountered AFAIK). Powerlock is a bit different than Powerlink -- powerlocks are one time use links due to tolerances involved in >=10 speed chains. So it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Blam We'll just close it. Then others can the duplicate with the alternate wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as it's a 9-speed power-link, you can. I have chains in all bikes connected this way and find it most convenient method. The one made by SRAM is also the easiest to open.

Comment: Theres also Wipperman Connex and KMC.